# Jackson Deserialization: how to avoid when changing the fields of an object

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I have a problem when using Jackson deserialization as my objects often change.

Basically I work with a team who changes object quite often. They add field or change field structure.

I've managed to fix the first problem (new fields) by adding `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`.

However it doesnt work when a field already exist but has a different structure.

Example:

```
{
car: toyota
}
```

is changed to

```
 {
    car:{
           name: toyota,
           color: red
    }
    }
```

How can I manager this error, ie the deserialization works but doesn't take the changed field into account?

Comment: the only thing I can suggest is to use custom deserializer

Comment: What is this supposed to be, JSON?